# Meaning of ? and $ in htaccess rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know the basic rewrite rule in .htaccess file. but i can't find the meaning of highlighed `?` and `$`:

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/`?`([a-zA-Z]*)`?`/`?`([a-zA-Z0-9]*)`?`/`?$`  index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]

**Formatted rule code:**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

Can someone tell what they used here. I am trying myself but can't find this anywhere . any help would be very appreciated

Comment: @anubhava  I just want to know meaning of firsts  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is more of regex rather than a .htaccess one. Let me try to to answer:

- `?` in regex means 0 or 1 match or to make something an **optional** match
- `$` is end anchor in regex that means the end of input.

Your rewrite rule appears to be making both `action` and `id` components optional and this rule allows for an optional trailing slash at the end of the pretty URI.

Comment: thanks sir, but   in my case all three are optional , i mean when i open localhost , the GET array is       Array ( [controller] => [action] => [id] => )

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]` is your rule. That is happening due to quantifier `*` used in regex which matches given character class 0 or more tomes.

Comment: then i think i really not need `?` and `$` there. have they  any use  in my case. can you please explain little more.

Comment: If you want to make every component optional then `?` is still needed since `?` is being used after `/` to make `/` optional as well. Also `$` is always a good practice to use to avoid matching unwanted URIs.

Comment: thanks . but i am still confused., i think i should learn regexp first. but they are very complex can you tell a easy link for regular experssion